# Packages.config vs Dependency section in .nuspec file

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I am new to nuget and trying got understand where I should define my dependencies.  There is the  section in my .nuspec file and then there is the list of dependencies in packages.config.  What is used when?

Answer (score 4):

When building your assembly, NuGet uses the `packages` section in the **packages.config** file to determine which NuGet packages to download.

When installing a package, NuGet uses the `dependencies` section in **.nuspec** files to determine which *additional* NuGet packages to install. Of course, those additional NuGet packages can require their own additional NuGet packages.

When creating a **.nuspec** file, typically you include one `dependency` entry for each `package` entry you find in **packages.config** (skip `package` entries with a `developmentDependency="true"` attribute). But, if you want, you can also skip any `package` entries that your assembly doesn't reference directly - the indirectly referenced packages should be covered by the `dependency` entries in the packages that your project does reference directly. In practice, I have found it safer just to include all directly and indirectly referenced packages due to bugs in dependency lists of referenced packages.